# Subtract an image from an other one

Tags: python, image

I am trying to subtract an average image from an other.
Here is what I did :

```
Avv=Image.open("Average.tiff")
os.chdir("D://ESSAI_1//Bulle")
dir_bubble=os.listdir("D://ESSAI_1//Bulle")
tiff_bubble=[filename for filename in dir_bubble if  filename[-5:] ==".tiff"]
new_image = ImageChops.subtract(tiff_bubble, Avv)
out=Image.fromarray(new_image)
out.save("Contrasted.tiff")
out.show()
```

But I have this error message :

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'load'
```

Comment: you are passing `tiff_bubble` (a list) into your `ImageChops.subtract`, which expects two images as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new_image = ImageChops.subtract(tiff_bubble, Avv)`

`subtract`'s first argument should be an Image object. `tiff_bubble` is not an Image object, it is a list of strings.

Try making `tiff_bubble` an Image.

```
possible_filenames = [filename for filename in dir_bubble if  filename[-5:] ==".tiff"]
tiff_bubble = Image.open(possible_filenames[0])
```

Comment: Thank you ! But now the image has the wrong mode, I tried convert it using new_image.convert('L') but it still doesn't work

Comment: `new_image.convert('L')` doesn't do anything by itself, for the same reason that `x+4` doesn't change the value of `x`. You've got to do something with the result. try `new_image = new_image.convert('L')`